# Saving to Core Data Every Second Performance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Here is the situation:

I'm working on app that wants to update a duration property on my NSManagedObject subclass of a particular audible/viewable item such as a song or a video. This information is important so it needs to be as accurate as possible

Solution 1 would be to update this after the item finishes playing, but if the user terminates the application from memory wether they are in the foreground or background, then this introduces another problem on how to handle.

Solution 2 (what seems to be definitely the easiest solution) would be to just update this single duration property every second via a timer like so where the core data logic happens in the updateDuration method:

```
updateTimer = Timer.every(1.0, {
     self.updateDuration(for: self.itemNeedingUpdate)
})
RunLoop.current.add(updateTimer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
```

My question is "Is this a bad thing to do?" All save operations are handled on a background thread and if the item is paused or stopped, then the timer is also stopped. Thus, save operations are only triggered when the item is actually being listened to or watched. I have tested this in my project and there doesn't seem to be any performance issues what so ever with this approach. However, it's raising a red flag in my head. I'd love to hear any insight anybody has on this particular solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the RAM and CPU testing features on Xcode? Are they normal?

Comment: @BenjaminLowry RAM and CPU doesn't appear to be affected. CPU is ranging in the 2-4% while the timer is triggered.

Comment: Even if the app is force quit'ed your app gets notified that it is closing so why not update core data then?

Comment: @mthud those notifications are not reliable, and may not happen.

Answer (score 2):

I would just save your data in `applicationWillTerminate` (in your AppDelegate class) since it will be called when the app is about to terminate regardless of whether or not it is in background.

It should work with your video needs as well.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    saveData()
}
```

Saving every second is just going to be a bad use of a thread, that is unnecessary.

EDIT:

I should have made myself more clear that it is true that the method above isn't always called when the app is in the background. An easy solution to this is to also save your data every time the app enters the background:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    saveData()
}
```

I use this method for my own iOS app on the App Store, and I have not had any issues with it. Even if saving every second doesn't significantly affect your app's performance, it just seems unnecessary.

Comment: This method is only called when the app is terminated by the user while the app is the current running app. If the app is terminated while the app is in the background or if the system terminates it to free up memory, this method is not called. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

Comment: @dhint4 Yes, thanks for bringing that up, I forgot to explain that. See my edited post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand what your app is doing. But, saving once per second in order to maintain user data that will continuously change? I wouldn't hesitate to do that.

Comment: Tom, just to clarify, your saying that my proposed solution seems logical and ok to do?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wouldn't hesitate to use it.